# "Invalid argument" error for sysctl vm.drop_caches key in Ubuntu 11.10 (kernel 3.0.0-12)

Tags: linux, memory-management, ubuntu, sysctl

I have the following shell script that I've been using in previous versions of Ubuntu (<= 11.04) to clear memory cache and it has worked fine:

```
sudo sync && sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3 && sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=0
```

I have a new clean install of 11.10 with 3.0.0-12-generic kernel and I get the following error when running the same script script:

> vm.drop_caches = 3
>
> error: "Invalid argument" setting key "vm.drop_caches"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation/sysctl/vm.txt:

```
To free pagecache:
        echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
To free dentries and inodes:
        echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
To free pagecache, dentries and inodes:
        echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
```

You can't setting this to zero.

Comment: thanks, I'll try it. Did you try with vm.drop_caches=0? That is specifically where I was getting the error. 3 worked fine.

Comment: My `/proc/sys/vm/drop_caches` had `0` by default. I set it to 3, 2, 1, now can't return it to default state.